# CakePHP model conventions - relation to relation

Tags: cakephp

I have these tables:
questions, question_sets.

So it's along with convention to do:
questions_question_sets.

Right? Next, I have this table:
answers.

Every questions_question_sets has many answers so I need to build a column name as singular. Is it going to be:
1. questions_question_set_id or
2. question_question_set_id?

I guess it should be the 1st but who knows...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR:**

```
questions_question_set_id
```

**Further details in case next person is trying to do something like this:**

Based on what you're trying to do, I'm going to assume a `Question` can belong to more than one `QuestionSet`, and an `Answer` is specific to a `Question` within a specific `QuestionSet` (as opposed to what seems logical to me - an `Answer` belongs to a `Question` regardless of which `QuestionSet` it's in).

**Models**

```
Question
QuestionSet
Answer
QuestionsQuestionsSet
```

**Tables**

```
questions
    id
question_sets
    id
answers
    id
    questions_question_set_id
questions_question_sets
    id
    question_id
    question_set_id
```

**Associations**

```
Question hasAndBelongsToMany QuestionSet
QuestionSet hasAndBelongsToMany Questions
Answer belongsTo QuestionsQuestionSet
QuestionsQuestionSet hasMany Answer
```

**Fields**

Comment: That's it but it can't be the "logical" way as every question has some attributes within some question set (e.g. one question needs to be the first to display in one set and e.g. third in other set). Anyway, thanks for answer!

Comment: Right, but is the answer to a question different based on quick question set it's in?  (and NP!  glad to help!)

Comment: It sounds more like you'd just want an "order" field in your questions_question_sets table.

Comment: and there is only this field there: order. But it's also better to know which question set was taken, like: "tell you what do you think about eirlier questions" or something... I just fell like I should prepare as much flexibity to the user as I can. :)